# Windows Installer/RunAs shortcut

Tags: winapi, windows-installer, shortcut, runas

I have an application on a server in our domain; it's written in C# and uses the Word API.  (The app runs through a list of medical reports, each a separate Word document, extracts information which it uses to alphabetize the patient on whom the report is made, and pushes the report content into a PDF.)  The app appears to run fine when run directly on the server.  It also runs correctly (using source code on the server) from Visual Studio on my machine.  However, I don't want to allow the users direct access to the server.  The solution I arrived at was to create a user with access to the server, then place a shortcut on the desktop which pointed to "runas $username $programname" . Up pops the authentication window, asking for the appropriate password.  When this is supplied, the program executes correctly up until the point where Word is invoked; then it starts Windows Installer.  I'm not sure what it's trying to install.  If this is canceled, I get the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005."  Am I doing something I shouldn't? Am I missing something?

Comment: If they already know the password, what is stopping them from just running runas /user:$user cmd.exe? Why not just put the app in a read-only share that everyone can read?

Comment: It already is in a read-only share that everyone can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Word is attempting to do some kind of first use initialization or install repair.

Comment: Actually, that seems to have been it - we re-created the Normal.dot template and that fixed it.